# Regex to match text using two alterations

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to achieve the following in RegEx (C#):

The pattern should match a word (say aaa). The word can have a prefix, which can be one of three options (say a,b,c).

Problem is, the words I'm looking for can be a combination of prefix + other words. For example, the word aaaa is a stand alone word, but also the prefix a and the word aaa.

What pattern can I use so that a word like that (aaaa) will match the word, and not the prefix + shorter word?

The pattern I'm using now is this:

```
(?<prefix>a|b|c)?(?<word>aaa|aaaa)
```

However, as mentioned above, this pattern will match aaaa as the 'aaa' word with a prefix 'a'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding an empty prefix, just add a `|` before the first actual prefix:

```
(?<prefix>|a|b|c)(?<word>aaaa|aaa)
```

Of course with an empty prefix, you no longer need to make your prefix group optional since the first thing it will try to match with is an empty prefix.

Note that I also switched the order of your words (`aaaa` before `aaa`), in general if you have multiple expressions within an alternation where one is a prefix of another, you want to put the longer one first.

Example: http://rubular.com/r/bZfAy89xkR